# Change the mask for few numpy arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, mask

So, I have on the input few masked arrays. For computation I use slices: top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right:

```
dy0 = dy__[:-1, :-1]
dy1 = dy__[:-1, 1:]
dy2 = dy__[1:, 1:] 
dy3 = dy__[1:, :-1]
```

The same is done with dx and g values.
To compute sums or differences correctly I need to change the mask to make it the same for all of them. For now I count the sum of converted into int masks of 4 arrays and check if it's more than one. So if there is more than one masked element - I mask it.

```
import functools
sum = functools.reduce(lambda x1, x2: x1.astype('int') + x2.astype('int'), list_of_masks)
mask = sum > 1  # mask output if more than 1 input is masked
```

But when I initialize masks like    `dy0.mask = new_mask`    they don't change.
Also when I replace 0 elements in one array with 1 using    `numpy.where()`    the mask disappears, so I can initialize the new one. But for those arrays which stay the same mask still doesn't change. (I checked the numpy.ma documentation, and it should)

The problem is in some functions there are too many arrays which mask might be changed to the new one, so it's better to find a good way to initialize it in one operation for few arrays and be sure it works.
Is there any way to do it or to find why it doesn`t work as it should?